# How to understand Trisyllables in poetry?

Tags: poetry, meter

I can understand usually when a foot in poetry is iambic or trochaic, however I am a bit confused when a foot is comprised of 3 syllables. Is there poetry written with this? And how do you tell where the strong and weak beats are?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactyl_(poetry)

Comment: https://mammothmemory.net/english/literature/poetry-feet-and-metres/anapestic-tetrameter.html

Comment: Doesn't iambic have three syllables, too?

Comment: This question might be a suitable candidate for migration to [SE Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com) where there are tags for Poetry and meter.

Comment: [William Cullen Bryant](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+only+feet+of+three+syllables%22) (1889) - *The only feet of three syllables which can be employed in English iambics are either those which  have the two first short and the third long or those which have all three short —the **anapest** and the **tribrach**. A certain use of these feet in that kind of verse has been allowed from the very beginnings of English poetry when the two first syllables in these feet are vowels or diphthongs , as in the following instance : **To scorn delights and live laboriously***.

Answer (score 1):

A 'foot' can be of (theoretically) any number of syllables, although the iambic and trochaic feet are now the most common.  The reason why these two are the most common is that, as Aristotle said of the iambus, they are the nearest to the rhythms of ordinary speech,

> in wh**í**ch we t**é**nd to **é**mphas**í**se altérnate
> s**ÿ**lla**bles**.
>
> You can **see** that the cl**au**se I just wr**o**te was i**a**mbic.

But this last sentence (beginning with "You" and ending with "iambic") is not, and that the repeated pattern involves groups of three syllables:  two unstressed and one stressed.

The words *iambic* and **trochaic** are ancient Greek in origin. The earliest tragedies had their spoken lines in trochaic tetrameters (four trochaic feet, each of two trochees, per line): the trochaic foot consisted of what we would regard as two feet (t**ú**m-ti-t**ú**m-ti).  Most of those that survive had their dialogue in iambic trimeters (ti-t**ú**-ti-t**ú**m), equivalent to six Shakespearean hexameters.  Shakespeare's metre, of course, is called *iambic pentameter*, consisting of what would now be regarded as five iambic feet, each half as long as the ancient iambus.

But the epics of Homer and the obscure philosophical writings of Heraclitus were written in a different metre, called the *hexameter*, of which the basis is the **three-syllable** you were asking about, with a 'foot', called the *dactyl* (the Greek for a forefinger with its one longer bone and two shorter bones):  it consists of one stressed followed by two unstressed syllables.

But there is a 'but'.  You will struggle to find much in verse written in English of any century using metres with trisyllabic feet.   I found one for children in Allan Ahlberg's *Please Mrs Butler*.

- D**ó**g in the / pl**áy**ground,/ s**ú**ddenly / th**é**re
- Smile on his face, tail in the air

But the truth of the matter is that for most European languages I know, including Greek, it is very difficult.  Even the above is not entirely dactylic.  But the first would count as the first three and a half feet of a hexameter.  Of course, 'playground' is not itself a dactyl, being only of two syllables.  But this could be regarded as two stressed syllables, which, in ancient verse was called a *spondee* (tum-tum).  A spondee can replace a dactyl because two unstressed syllables were treated as equivalent to one stressed syllable.  This allowed rhythmic variety.

However, there is no doubt that trisyllabic feet can feature even in basically iambic poems. For example TS Elliot's poem, *Rhapsody on a Windy Night*

- Half past two
- The street lamp said
- Remark the cat which **fláttens it/sélf in the** gutter,
- **slips out its** tongue
- and devours a morsel of rancid butter.

The freer the verse becomes, of course, the more open to doubt any interpretation of the rhythmic flow.  In ancient Greek and Roman poetry, there were formal rules about which syllables were stressed and which unstressed.  It was about 'length' rather than stress, and was governed partly by the position of a vowel (always long before two consonants - except 'r'; in Greek *alpha and omega are naturally long, in both languages dipthongs...*).

Comment: The Ancient Greek terms referred to syllable length, rather than accentuation: an iamb was a short syllable followed by a long syllable. Modern English speech is certainly not “naturally” iambic in either sense; I don’t know if Aristotle was accurately describing the rhythm of Ancient Greek.

Comment: @herisson Yes, I expressed myself badly.  I should know:  I spend a few years at school converting English poems into Latin hexameters or pentameters.  I'll try to clarify tomorrow while Storm Eunice howls outside.

Comment: [This poem](http://www.councilofelrond.com/poem/errantry/) uses dactylic rhyme.

Comment: Most [limericks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerick_(poetry)) are written in trisyllables. For example, [these](https://www.englishmatters.org/documents/Limericks.pdf).  *There was an Old Man with a beard, // Who said, 'It is just as I feared!
// Two Owls and a Hen, //
Four Larks and a Wren, //
Have all built their nests in my beard!'*

Comment: @PeterShor Of course!  I should have thought of them. I think these are essentially anapaestic in movement (ti-ti-tum  ti-ti-tum ti-ti-tum ri-tu-tum...  Often they start with two stressed (long) syllables as in "There once / was a man / in a mac,   who as stuck on the top of a stack "  I don't know how it continues.